# How to display MathML equation in React Native app using MathJax?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mathjax

I tried to display MathML equation in my react native app using MathJax, but it is not showing. In the code below, the equation is not displayed, only "Helloworld".

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';
import MathJax from 'react-native-mathjax'

export default class TipsAndTricksScreen extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Tips And Tricks',
    };

    render() {
        return (

            <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                <MathJax math={String.raw`<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><msqrt><mn>2</mn><mfrac bevelled="true"><mn>7</mn><mn>7</mn></mfrac></msqrt><mo>+</mo><mfrac><mn>5</mn><mn>8</mn></mfrac></math>this is just a string`} />
                <Text>Helloworld</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the extension "react-native-mathjax"?

Comment: @Perniferous Yes, I did. I couldn't find what I was looking for though. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-mathjax

Comment: It doesn't look like the prop "math" exists in any of the docs. Where did you get that?

Comment: @Perniferous I had tried that syntax with reactjs and it worked. I am not able to make it work here.

Comment: Well this react-native library differs from a normal react implementation.

Comment: @Perniferous ok could you help me with this? I am a beginner at react native. I want to display the MathML equation.

Answer (score 2):

It seems quite straight forward to implement the dependency.  Looking at the source code of the dependency it looks like it is just a wrapper around a Webview, so just be aware that it will probably only work if you are online.

The dependency has some default options already set for `MathJax` and you can pass further options using the `mathJaxOptions` prop. So if we pass

```
{
  jax: ['input/MathML']
}
```

then it should tell `MathJax` that you are passing `MathML` as a input.

So here is a simple component that uses `react-native-mathjax`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import MathJax from 'react-native-mathjax';

const mmlOptions = {
    jax: ['input/MathML'],
};

class MathView extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <MathJax
          mathJaxOptions={mmlOptions}
          html={'<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><msqrt><mn>2</mn><mfrac bevelled="true"><mn>4</mn><mn>7</mn></mfrac></msqrt><mo>+</mo><mfrac><mn>5</mn><mn>8</mn></mfrac></math> this is just a string'}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default MathView;
```

This would give you something like this

[image]

That should be enough to get you started. You can pass additional options via the `mathJaxOptions` prop. You just need to look at the `MathJax` [documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/config-files.html) for all the different things that you can pass.

**Caveat**

On Android it doesn't look like the Android WebView can render MathML, there maybe a configuration that will make it work but I don't know it, however the Android WebView does render LaTex, so perhaps converting your MathML to LaTex could be a fallback option for you.

Comment: That works well when I try to display LaTex string. However, if I try to display MathML string, it doesn't work.                 <MathJax html={String.raw`<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><msqrt><mn>2</mn><mfrac bevelled="true"><mn>7</mn><mn>7</mn></mfrac></msqrt><mo>+</mo><mfrac><mn>5</mn><mn>8</mn></mfrac></math>this is just a string`} />

Comment: You would need to look at MathJax and see if they have methods for using it offline - if you look at `react-native-mathjax` you can see there is a current open issue about offline usage. Currently no-one has come up with an implementation. https://github.com/calvinkei/react-native-mathjax/issues/6

Comment: It loads really slow. Is there a way to load them fast. Data gets loaded initially, then after 10 to 15 seconds the size gets adjusted again.

Comment: Sorry. I have no idea. I don’t really use this in any of my projects. There was an issue opened a year ago about the same problem. https://github.com/calvinkei/react-native-mathjax/issues/21 I would suggest contacting the package builder but the last commit on the repo was 2 years ago so it may no longer be maintained.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to render MathML in React Native, you'll need some extensions and of course input and output method. After some research, I found this solution particular for MML to HTML:

```
<MathJax
  html={`<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><msqrt><mn>2</mn><mfrac bevelled="true"><mn>7</mn><mn>7</mn></mfrac></msqrt><mo>+</mo><mfrac><mn>5</mn><mn>8</mn></mfrac></math>this is just a string`}
  mathJaxOptions={{messageStyle: 'none',
   extensions:    
  ['mml2jax.js','MathMenu.js','MathZoom.js','AssistiveMML.js','a11y/accessibility- 
  menu.js',],
   jax: ['input/MathML', 'output/CommonHTML'],
    tex2jax: {
      inlineMath: [['$', '$'], ['\\(', '\\)']],
      displayMath: [['$$', '$$'], ['\\[', '\\]']],
      processEscapes: true,},
    TeX: {extensions:['AMSmath.js','AMSsymbols.js','noErrors.js','noUndefined.js'],},}} />
```